Moving std::thread with references
I have a class that has a thread like so:
// USING C++ 17
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

class MyClass {
    std::thread thread;
    std::string mystring;

public:
    bool done = false;

    MyClass(std::string string) {
        mystring = string;

        thread = std::thread(&MyClass::worker, std::ref(*this));
        thread.detach();
    }
    void worker() {
        // notice how mystring has the wrong value, some of the time
         std::cout << "mystring is: \"" << mystring << "\"" << std::endl;

         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

         done = true;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyClass> my_vec {};
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        my_vec.emplace_back("hello");
    }
    
    while (my_vec.size() > 0) {
        for (auto it = my_vec.begin(); it != my_vec.end();) {
            if (it->done) {
                it = my_vec.erase(it);
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        
    }

    return 0;
}

I want to store instances of MyClass in a std::vector. Every once in a while, I loop over the vector and remove the instances of MyClass that have finished (done is true).
However, when I emplace_back a new instance of MyClass onto my vector, instances of MyClass already in the vector have their move constructor is called. In this call, worker's refrence to this is not updated, so mystring still points to the old block of memory.
The loop is part of a GUI event loop, so I want to be able to use this pattern. - Is there any way to fix this or achieve this pattern?
I have tried overwriting MyClass's move constructor, using std::move to move the thread. I have also tried making worker a static method and passing a reference to the appropriate instance of MyClass.

Are you in a position to reserve such a large vector upfront, that resize never needs to re-allocate?

There are several ways of making something address-stable, but surely you should do something about having empty std::threads, not joining them, and having no synchronization among these threads at all?

Better make (done) into a std::atomic at least!

When your vector grows all references and iterators to elements in the vector are invalidated.  You need to be able to handle that.  Either use a layer of indirection (std::vector<std::uinique_ptr<Myclass>>) or pick an address stable container.

@DavisHerring ain't thread not joinable once detached? feels like OP doesn't need to detach in first place

@jupiterbjy: Exactly, and detach is already a last resort (since it basically makes it impossible to safely clean up thread_local variables and the like).

@jupiterbjy the threads are running alongside a GUI, which needs to process events from the OS in the main thread - thats why they are detatched.

@DavisHerring these threads are slicing large video files into frames, one video file per thread. so I don’t think there is a huge need to synchronize anything.

@JeremyFriesner maybe a good idea, but in practice this shouldn't matter. One thread is writing, the other is reading. It doesnt matter if the thread reading done has a race condition with the thread writing done. done only gets changed once, so the thread reading done will notice the change on the next iteration of the loop, which is perfectly fine in this case.

@Ethan Even if the data race in question is seemingly "benign", it is technically undefined behavior and therefore should be avoided. (The compiler might see that this variable is not written to at all in the current thread and replace the whole loop with either while(false) or while(true) based on what the initial value is).

@Ethan computers (and compilers) are more complicated these days, so intuitions about what "shouldn't matter" can be misleading.  You might "get lucky" for years and everything works as you expect, until one day you run on a different CPU or compile on a different compiler and your program suddenly isn't working correctly, so it's better not to chance it.  If nothing else, it will cause race-detector tools (like helgrind or ThreadSanitizer) to emit a bunch of (valid!) warnings, potentially confusing or obscuring other thread-safety issues and making it harder for you to understand/fix them.

Adding a layer of indirection (changing my_vec from std::vector<MyClass> to std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>) solved this problem thanks to @NathanOliver's comment.
I am using my_vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<MyClass>("hello")); to instantiate MyClass.
In the example given in the problem, when an exception occurs in the thread done never gets set to true and the program assumes the thread is still running.
To solve this problem, I changed the std::thread to a std::future and start the worker asynchronously with
std::future<int> thread = std::async(
   std::launch::async,
   [this] {
       worker();
       return 0;
    });

This way, I can check if the async function is still running using the answer shown here.
